# Bind specific parameter (one) in JPQL

Tags: jpa-2.0, bind, eclipselink, jpql

In database I have partitioning table by column 'status' for better performance. My database administrator ask me about put in query value for that column directly in sql (not bind by parameter).

I can change binding by set hint QueryHints.BIND_PARAMETERS on false, but then all parameters are inside sql.

Can I set not bind only on 'status' parameter ?

Example result when BIND_PARAMETERS = true

```
SELECT t0.* FROM S_JOBS_ORG_UNIT_CFG t0 
WHERE ((((t0.ORG_ID = ?) AND (t0.SCHEDULER_NEXT_ACTIVATION < SYSDATE)) AND (t0.ACTIVE = ?)) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ? FROM S_JOBS t1 WHERE (((t1.ORDER_ID = t0.ORDER_ID) AND (t1.ORG_ID = t0.ORG_ID)) AND NOT ((t1.STATUS = ?)))) )
bind => [472100, Y, 1, E]
```

and result when BIND_PARAMETERS = false

```
SELECT t0.* FROM S_JOBS_ORG_UNIT_CFG t0 
WHERE ((((t0.ORG_ID = 472100) AND (t0.SCHEDULER_NEXT_ACTIVATION < SYSDATE)) AND (t0.ACTIVE = Y)) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM S_JOBS t1 WHERE (((t1.ORDER_ID = t0.ORDER_ID) AND (t1.ORG_ID = t0.ORG_ID)) AND NOT ((t1.STATUS = E)))) )
```

Code:

```
        Query jobOrgUnitCfgQuery = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT c FROM JobOrgUnitCfg c WHERE c.orgId = :orgId and c.schedulerNextActivation < current_timestamp and c.active = :active and " +
            " not exists (SELECT j  FROM Job j WHERE j.orderId = c.orderId and j.orgId = c.orgId and j.status <> 'E')");

    jobOrgUnitCfgQuery.setParameter("orgId", orgId);
    jobOrgUnitCfgQuery.setParameter("active", Boolean.TRUE);
    return jobOrgUnitCfgQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I  think your best bet is just to programmatically build your query like you're doing with a hard coded status and escape the other paramaters manually to avoid SQL Injection.